# ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to connect to my university server from home on my Linux Mint 18.3 using ssh. I have set up a VPN that the school recommended, it says it's connected.

I am using the command `ssh username@hostname`.
However, after a while, there's an error: ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out.
I also tried to replace the hostname with the IP address, but nothing changed.
If I run `ssh -vvv username@hostname` this is what it says:

[image]

I have also installed OpenSSH, when I check if it is enabled and active, it says it is. I tried to restart it, too.

I can `ping`, but `telnet` doesn't work, it just says: trying (ip address).

If I try `nslookup`, it can see the IP address.

Also, `sudo netstat -tulpn` shows that port 22 is listening.

I think the problem might be related to the firewall, but when I tried `sudo ufw allow ssh` and `sudo ufw allow 22` that didn't help.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: You're probably behind a firewall, brother.filtering port 22. You need to know more about the kind of connection you are connecting from (ISP or LAN or else)